# Install Python 3.7.x on Windows Subsytem Debian 9.6

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, debian, debian-stretch

When attempting to update my Python version from 3.53 to 3.7 I run

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

but no upgrade is performed, I only see this message:

```
python3 is already the newest version (3.5.3-1)
```

However I know that Python 3.7.1 is already released as a major version and don't know how else to install it.

Is there anyway to update my Python version in my linux subsystem manually?

Comment: You'd have to either: 1) add the testing apt sources to get the latest python from Debian Testing; 2) Add the Python 3.7 ppa and install it from it ([look here](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.7)); 3) Download Python 3.7 source code by hand and compile it yourself. I'd suggest you number 2.

Comment: That's perfect, #2 worked for me. Thanks!